# Why is there "no difference" in size between font-size 12 and 13?

Tags: windows, fonts

This is a screencap of the font-dialog in Visual Studio 2013. Notice that the difference between size 12 and 13 isn't actually much of a size-difference, it just renders the font slightly different. Why is that? (The same happens with other fonts also. Not just Source Code Pro)

[image: Screencap]

Comment: In the figure it is displaying some diff

Comment: Yes, but not as significant as from 11 to 12, or 13 to 14.

Answer (score 0):

Windows renders fonts for screen display, respecting the pixel characteristics of screen pixels.  This is less useful with modern screen technology.

Traditionally, Apple, Macs, and Apple/Mac applications like Adobe Illustrator and Postscript, render fonts for printing, and try to scale screen display to match what you will get on paper. This is not as different with modern screen technology.

I'm a screen user: I prefer traditional MS rendering. On the other hand, all print/layout/web designers/artists prefer 'exact' rendering.